# TypeScript check for empty string

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Is there a way for TypeScript to statically check for an empty string? Is there a way to statically require a non-empty string to be passed to a function?

```
let fn = function(a:string){

};

fn('');
```

or

```
let a = '';
fn(a);
```

Can TS help us here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe this is as close as you're going to get only using the typing system (rather than having a 'nonEmptyString' class)

```
type nonEmptyString = never; // Cannot be implicitly cast to
function isNonEmptyString(str: string): str is nonEmptyString {
    return str && str.length > 0; // Or any other logic, removing whitespace, etc.
}
```

Testing it:

```
let fn = function(a: nonEmptyString) {

}

let someStr = '';
if (isNonEmptyString(someStr)) {
    fn(someStr); // Valid
} else {
    fn(someStr); // Compile error
}
```

Unfortunately, you end up with warts since `nonEmptyString` is `never`. Which means you need to explicitly cast `nonEmptyString` back to `string`.

```
let fn = function(a: nonEmptyString) {
    let len = a.length; // Invalid
    let len2 = (<string>a).length; // Valid
    let str = a + 'something else'; // Valid (str is now typed as string)
}
```

One possible resolution is:

```
type nonEmptyString = string & { __nonEmptyStr: never };
```

Which alleviates the problem of having to explicitly cast back to a string (all three tests above are valid), but does pollute the type with `__nonEmptyStr` (which will be `undefined` if referenced).

Comment: maybe we could require an object with a toString method, that also would work, just a different type of solution.

Comment: Except I think all objects have a toString method...hmm.

Comment: Why not just use the `string` type then: ```const isNotBlank = (str?: string|null): str is string => (str !== undefined && str !== null && str.trim().length > 0)```? Genuine question - what would be wrong with this approach?.

Comment: @Anoiny That works for checking if it's not empty, but how would you use that to define a function which required a non empty string?

Answer (score 24):

You can use this trick in your specific case:

```
function fn<T extends string>(a: T extends '' ? never : T) {
  // But TypeScript won't know here that !!a === true
}

fn(''); // Error
fn('foo'); // No error
```

Comment: The only right answer for the question. It totally works and doesn't involve static type checking.

Comment: Is there any way to do this for an interface rather than function params? e.g. 
```
type NonEmptyString = ....;
interface Props {
  content: NonEmptyString;
}
```

Comment: you can turn this into a utility type `type NonEmptyString<T> = T extends '' ? never : T`

Answer (score 3):

You could maybe type it with overloads such as to give a bad return type on `""` that will make things error as soon as you use it elsewhere:

```
type MyFnType = {
  (a: "") => never;
  (a: string) => whatever;
}

function fn: MyFnType = ...
```

Comment: for some reason, the above syntax is not compiling , but I agree with the solution

Comment: This solution works, but as already noted this example won't compile. Here is an example that will: https://codesandbox.io/s/jnbu6 – it does function overloading e.g. `function fn(s: ''): never; function fn(s: string): string; function fn(s: string | '') {/* do the real work here *}`

Answer (score 3):

**Workaround**

```
type NonEmpty<T extends string = string> = T extends '' ? never : T
// or extends NonNullable
type NonNull<T> = T extends string ? NonEmpty<T> : NonNullable<T>
```

Note! It only works with [Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and [Generic Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types), not works with [Primitives Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean) `string`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwKIFsygDwBUoQB7AQIAmAzlKcAE4CWCA5lALwXV30B8zUO+hJ5AOSCoAfigIIANwhUoALh4AoUJFiIYAVwA227Fxa8CRMq1oMx65GkxYui+Ai26AhgCNtEfUpXhoOFkEXEQAfKEE3QV81LAhKbgBvJSgUqFUIRSTU7Kg6KRdtGmIHDR09O2SclPzC4qtnco5KlIBfZqh6IlkaAGMsP0z27LyCosV9AAoXEqcy-QBKZi4pOCKh1JqxqEnp+rm7RaZl1eJ2traexHjCSkVY+JYs1PTBqpSR2sVhABp16tG6kEotkWr9sp1JLQ+gMoE8qh8ihNFgkoKC-lBNsQkbDUWclG0bsAAHQQ7rQyBEhFY4TzFRxYmkqH9CmYiZA2lAA)

Comment: In fact, if I don't consider historical factors, I prefer to name `NonNull` as `Valuable`.

Comment: but `const foo: NonEmpty = ''` will result in `foo` being of type `string`

Answer (score -3):

You can use `!a` to check if `a` is an empty string.

Comment: Not an answer, because question is about static type check in TypeScript, not run-time check in JavaScript.

Answer (score -4):

The snipet below controls if the string is empty and even if there is empty space string

```
private checkRequired(text:string){
        if(text == null) return false;
        let n = text.length; 
        for (let i = 1; i < n; i++){
            if (text[i] !== " "){
                return true;
            }
        }  
        return false;
      }

if(this.checkRequired("bla bla blast")){
 ... do your stuff 
}
```

Comment: Please don't use this. It's missing a check against undefined and instead of checking if each character is a space, you could call .trim() and see if the result has length 0. Yes, this is slower, but much more readable. Then again, is a string with spaces in it really empty? OP didn't indicate that

Answer (score -5):

Go to tsconfig.json in your project add this code  under  `"strict":true,`

`"strictNullChecks": false,`  it will solve your problem