# NonEmptyString type in Typescript without generic

Tags: typescript, types, template-literals

I want to ensure that the string type has at least one character in it, but as a type and not needing a generic.

This is a solution with generics.

```js
export type NonEmptyString<K extends string> = Exclude<K, "">
export type Extension<K extends string> = `.${NonEmptyString<K>}`

declare function extension<K extends string>(ext: Extension<K>): void

extension(".") // error
extension(".a") // okay
```

For my use case, the following works without generics but only works when at least one char is defined at the start.

```js
export type Extension = `.${string}${string}`;
declare function extension(ext: Extension): void

extension(".") // error
extension(".a") // success
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688840/typescript-check-for-empty-string ?

Comment: This isn't really possible; TypeScript lacks subtraction/negated types, and there are no "character classes" we can use in template literal types.  You can fake one up like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N533MW), where we make up our own `Char` type consisting of just printable ascii characters.  This sort of works (unless you care about nonprintable and non-ascii characters) but isn't great.  You can use generics, but you don't want that.  Would you accept an answer that says "no" along with links to the missing features necessary?  Or do you want something else?